# Display ng-disabled as enabled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have disabled an element using ng-disabled but although I want to disable the button but make it appear as if its still enabled. Is it possible?

This is how I have disabled the button-

```
<button class="button button-block button-assertive"  
        ng-click="disable()" 
        ng-disabled="isDisabled" 
        ng-model="isDisabled">
    <div style="text-align:center;">Register</div>
</button>
```

Comment: Don't use ng-disabled?

Comment: @RalfdeKleine what other possible way can I disable a button?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it only to appear as if it still enabled, you can just change the class of the button, depending on the isDisabled value:

```
<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-class="{'class-one' : isDisabled}" 
        ng-click="disable()" 
        ng-disabled="isDisabled" 
        ng-model="isDisabled">
    <div style="text-align:center;">Register</div>
</button>
```

Here is documentation on ng-class:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass